# Optional group in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have lines I'm trying to match that could be:

```
ACDNT: BLAHBLAH COUNTY, NC
ACDNT: BLAHBLAH COUNTY, NC PERS INJ
ACDNT: BLAHBLAH COUNTY, NC CMV
ACDNT: SOMEWHERE ELSE
```

So I want a regular expression that matches "ACDNT: ", a location with or without the NC county, and then either nothing, "PERS INJ", or "CMV". I want to capture the location and the 'extra' (PERS INJ or CMV) in groups.

I'm trying:

```
(ACDNT: +)(.*)( +(CMV|PERS INJ))?
```

with the test string:

```
ACDNT: SOMEWHERE PERS INJ
```

and regex101 (with the Java option) matches 'SOMEWHERE PERS INJ' as group 2. I was expecting "PERS INJ" to be in its own group.

I thought the trailing question mark would make the group enclosing the space and the last text optional. How would alter the regular expression to do that?

To summarize, I want to match the location (whether it's an NC county or not) as its own group, then have an optional group that has one of the two 'extra' strings if they're there.

("a programmer had a problem and decided to solve it with regular expressions. Now he has two problems...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(ACDNT: +)(.*?)( +(CMV|PERS INJ))?$`

Your problem is that `.*` is greedy and consumes the entire rest of the string--that's why you're seeing "SOMEWHERE PERS INJ" all in the same group. I changed `*` to `*?` to make it reluctant instead of greedy, and I added `$` at the end to force the matcher to consider the whole string.

There are still some caveats. Note that an input consisting of "ACDNT: " followed by any string will still be a successful match. You could help address this by being more specific with what's allowed for the location instead of `.*`.

Comment: Actually, there are no rules for what might follow the space after ACDNT:, so a successful match there fits my case. If it IS a county in NC, I want to be able to separate that out from other strings, but that's a different problem. Extra thanks for explaining how to overcome the greedy qualifier.

Comment: Well, still have some sort of problem. Regex of `(ACDNT: +)(.*?) +(CMV|PERS INJ)?` and target string of `ACDNT: PERSON COUNTY, NC CMV` gives group 2 of `PERSON`; I wanted group 2 to be `PERSON COUNTY, NC` and group 3 to be CMV. Suggestions? I thought processing would attempt to match from the back of the string and give up characters until CMV was discovered.

Comment: ok, I guess I fixed that -- putting the `$` at the end allows it to discover `CMV` or `PERS INJ` after the rest of the text.